# Can't make downloadable product to be in stock

Tags: magento-1.8, product

I cant make product be available(in stock) to add them to cart,

1. I change settings in product manage(make it "in stock" and add Qty)
2. I also choose no in system > conf > catalog > inventory > Manage Stock
3. I refresh index management
4. I use default layout
5. I didn't change anything in code

Products are still shown as out of stock and I cant add any to cart, how can I solve that because I have no idea now.

Comment: Have you done any alteration in code?

Comment: I have solution if anyone had this problem

I didn't say that it was downloadable product and if you didnt give anything to download it will be shown as out of stock change it in product manage > Downloadable Information

Comment: Please add this as an answer and select it as solution in two days, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I have solution if anyone had this problem

I didn't say that it was downloadable product and if you didnt give anything to download it will be shown as out of stock change it in product manage > Downloadable Information